# Mcq Answer Grid

Tags: tables, grids

I'm trying to create beautiful Mcq (Multiple Choice Question) Answer Grid so could someone help me please to improve it with the following needs:

- Add Arguments to get automatic row-column numbers in grid table
- to mark correct answer automatic with `\ding{53}`

The input would resemble `\McqAnswerGrid{<number of questions>}{<number of choices>}{<correct cells>}` where the `<number of choices>` should be alphabetically enumerated and `<correct cells>` is a list of lists containing possible correct choices.

Here is an example of input of arguments you can make your own or adapt with that one:

- **Indicate all the answers that apply**

  ```
  \McqAnswerGrid{6}{6}{ {1,2,3},{1,6},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4},{2,4} }
  ```

  implies we have 6 question with 6 choices A, B, C, D, E, and F where answers that apply to

  - Question 1 are 1, 2, and 3
  - Question 2 are 1, and 6
  - Question 3 are 1, and 3
  - Question 4 are 2, and 3
  - Question 5 are 2, and 4
  - Question 6 are 2, and 4

  [image]
- **Select one answer choice**

  ```
  \McqAnswerGrid{5}{4}{ {1},{1},{3},{2},{4} }
  ```

  implies we have 5 question with 4 choices A, B, C, and D where the correct answer for

  - Question 1 is 1
  - Question 2 is 1
  - Question 3 is 3
  - Question 4 is 2
  - Question 5 is 4

  [image]

Note that most books provide 4 choices for Mcq math, while others may provide 5 or 6 at most, so the maximum number of choices will be 6 at least and for the maximum number of questions 80 at least.

At first I tried with `tikz` and after that `tabular` but it takes lot of time to fill it manually.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
  \begin{scope}
    \draw (0, 0) grid (5,10);
  \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
N & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
1 & \ding{53}  & \ding{53}  &  \ding{53}   & & &   \\ \hline
2 &  \ding{53} &   &   &   & & \ding{53}\\ \hline
3 & \ding{53}   &   & \ding{53}  &  & &   \\ \hline
4 &   &  \ding{53} & \ding{53}   &  & &  \\ \hline
5 &   & \ding{53}   &  & \ding{53}  & &  \\ \hline
6 &   & \ding{53}   &  & \ding{53}  & &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
N & A & B & C & D  \\ \hline
1 & \ding{53}  &  &   &    \\ \hline
2 &  \ding{53} &   &   &   \\ \hline
3 &   &   & \ding{53}  &    \\ \hline
4 &   &  \ding{53} &   &    \\ \hline
5 &   &   &  & \ding{53}   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If someone can't make it with this input of arguments you can come up with your one solution to cover that problem.

Comment: You provided 6 "correct answers", yet there's only 5 questions/columns in `\McqAnswerGrid{10}{5}{1,1,3,2,4,2}`. Also, what would your the macro look like that would result in your picture? `\McqAnswerGrid{12}{4}{?}`...

Comment: Thanks but it was  just an example but to be accurate should be  '\McqAnswerGrid{10}{5}{1,1,3,2,4,2,...}' . for the macro  you can suggest me one

Comment: So `10` is the number of *questions* (N in your picture, running down) and `5` is the number of *choices* (A, B, C, D, E, for example)? You need to be very clear what you want. Specifics are important.

Comment: nope there is only 4 choices A B C D but i add one another colum for numbers

Comment: ...which seems superfluous, as you'll *always* have a column for the question numbers, and *always* have four choices.

Comment: but i don't  want number 10 and 4 fixed

Comment: It's still not clear how you got the `\ding{53}` in some locations. Surely they indicate incorrect choices made, but you never mention how they are obtained/used in your example.

Comment: you can repalce it with any command represent the same symbol. for my example to mark the correct answer by using number within { } each number indicate the correct cell which to be marked respectively

Comment: What would the command look like for the picture you posted? That is still really unclear to me and doesn't seem to match anything else. Why are some incorrect answers marked as such and some left blank? Why is there only one correct answer for 12 questions? Shouldn't there be one per question?

Comment: for the command '\ding{53}' for that kind of qcm there only one correct answer but you can make it editable to cover other situations like two or three correct questions

Comment: I agree with @cfr. My suggestion would be to show us two things: An example of an input and the *associated* output. Thus far you've shown some input, and a completely *unrelated* output.

Comment: alright give me moment

Comment: could you see my update now

Comment: Note that you can ping somebody - for example, @Werner - by putting an `@` in front of their user name. However, you can only ping one person per comment. (You don't need to do this if only you and one other person are commenting as the system will automatically ping the other person. But as soon as there are 3 of us, the system will only ping you as it is your question, and nobody else.)

Comment: What's the maximum number of choices and questions?

Comment: @cfr  most of books provide 4 choices for mcq math others may be 5 or 6 at most

Answer (score 3):

The following example provides `\McqAnswerGrid{<rows>}{<columns>}{<answer spec>}` and a duplicate `\McqOneAnswerGrid` (purely because they may mean different things). They're a duplicate of one another since they both use the same style input:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,xparse}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\correctsymbol}{$\times$}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\row@column@element}
  { m }
  {\@namedef{row@element@\therow@cnt @#1}{\correctsymbol}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\process@columns}
  { > { \SplitList { , } } m }
  {\stepcounter{row@cnt}\ProcessList{#1}{\row@column@element}}%

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\process@rows}%
  { > { \SplitList { , } } m }
  {\ProcessList{#1}{\process@columns}}

\newcounter{row@cnt}
\newcommand{\McqAnswerGrid}[3]{{%
  \def\row@elements{N}% Top left entry
  \let\tabularline\relax% Create non-expandable \tabularline (will be used later)
  \multido{\iColumn=1+1}{#2}{% Create first row
    \protected@xdef\row@elements{\row@elements & \@Alph{\iColumn}}}%
  % Construct the top row of answer grid
  \g@addto@macro\row@elements{ \\ \tabularline}% Add line
  \setcounter{row@cnt}{0}%
  \process@rows{#3}%
  \multido{\iRow=1+1}{#1}{%
    \protected@xdef\row@elements{\row@elements \iRow}
    \multido{\iColumn=1+1}{#2}{%
      \protected@xdef\row@elements{\row@elements & 
        \ifcsname row@element@\iRow @\iColumn\endcsname
          \csname row@element@\iRow @\iColumn\endcsname
        \fi}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\row@elements{ \\ \tabularline}%
  }%
  % Set actual answer grid
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{\number\numexpr#2+1}{c|} }
    \hline
    \global\let\tabularline\hline% Make sure \tabularline is equivalent to \hline
    \row@elements
  \end{tabular}
}}

\let\McqOneAnswerGrid\McqAnswerGrid

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\McqAnswerGrid{6}{6}{ {1,2,3},{1,6},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4},{2,4} }

\bigskip

\McqOneAnswerGrid{5}{4}{ {1},{1},{3},{2},{4} }

\end{document}
```

We construct the `tabular` using a series of loops that information from a list-processor. The list processor creates a macro `\row@element@<row>@<column>` containing the `\correctsymbol` if it is specified. Else, the macro doesn't exist. During expansion of the `tabular` construction, the existence of `\row@element@<row>@<column>` is tested and subsequently used.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for your work but could you make it breakable because when i put 80 for rows doesn't show all the rows

Comment: Could you add version which column is row

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LaTeX 3 solution.

It has the requested 3 arguments for the number of rows, the number of columns and the cells to be marked. It also has an optional argument that specifies the number of the first question in the table. That way you can "split" long tables in multiple shorter ones and place them next to each other.

```
\McqAnswerGrid     {5} {6}{ {1,2,3},{1,6},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4} }
\hspace{1cm}
\McqAnswerGrid [6] {5} {6}{ {1,2,3},{1,6},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4} }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pifont}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\McqAnswerGrid}{ O{1} m m m }{
    \begin{tabular}{|c*{#3}{|c}|}
        \hline
        \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {N}
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#3} {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {& \int_to_Alph:n{##1}}}
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\\\hline}
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {1} {#1+#2-1} {
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \splitted_seq{,}{#4}
            \exp_args:NNnx \seq_set_split:Nnn \splitted_again {,} {\seq_item:Nn \splitted_seq {##1-#1+1}}
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {##1}
            \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#3} {
                \seq_if_in:NnTF \splitted_again {####1} {
                    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {& \ding{53}}
                } {
                    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {& }
                }
            }
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\\\hline}
        }
        \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \McqAnswerGrid     {5} {6}{ {1,2,3},{1,6},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4} }
    \hspace{1cm}
    \McqAnswerGrid [6] {5} {6}{ {1,2,3},{1,6},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4} }

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you but could you make the argument like what you did for that question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285074/mcq-answer-grid-with-tikz

Comment: What do you mean? You can pefectly use `\McqAnswerGrid [7] {6} {6} {6,5,4,3,2,1}` if you want only one solution per question. I don't see a difference in arguments. The first one is optional and is the starting number, the second is the number of questions, the third is the number of possible answers and the fourth is a list of correct answers. The only difference I see is that this questions uses a comma separated list of solutions while the other question has a semi-colon separated list of solutions. But you could easily edit the code yourself to change this.

Comment: i'm talking about the list of correct answer like that     `\Mcqanswergrid {10} {4} {1;2;4;3;2;3;1;2;0;0}`

Comment: The only difference between `\McqAnswerGrid {10} {4} {1,2,4,3,2,3,1,2,0,0}` from this question and `\answergrid {10} {4} {1;2;4;3;2;3;1;2;0;0}` from the other question is the comma instead of the semi-colon. Is that what you want different? Then change the comma on line 14 and 15 to a semi-colon. If you want something else, you'll have to be more specific because right now `\McqAnswerGrid {10} {4} {1,2,4,3,2,3,1,2,0,0}` works exactly as expected.