# Optical Mark Reader answer-sheets?

Tags: formatting, exam

I found the following nice code in this question [Mcq Answer Grid with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285074/mcq-answer-grid-with-tikz) but I want to add name box on an `answergrid`

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\answergrid}{ O{1} m m m }{
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.5cm]
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq{;}{#4}
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#3} {\node at (##1+1,#2) {\int_to_Alph:n{##1}};}
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {1} {#1+#2-1} {
        \node at (0, #1+#2-##1-1) {Question}; \node at (1, #1+#2-##1-1) {##1};
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#3} {
            \node[draw,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (####1+1, ##1-#1) {};
            \int_compare:nNnTF {####1} = {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1+#2-##1}} {\node[fill,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (####1+1, ##1-#1) {};}{}
 }
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
}      
\ExplSyntaxOff

       \begin{document}

\sffamily\small

\answergrid      {20} {4} {0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}
\answergrid [21] {20} {4} {0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}

 \end{document}
```

Here is the Ouput

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simply adding the following line (change the used values to your needs):

```
\hfill Name: \hspace{2cm}\vspace{1cm}
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\answergrid}{ O{1} m m m }{
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.5cm]
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq{;}{#4}
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#3} {\node at (##1+1,#2) {\int_to_Alph:n{##1}};}
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {1} {#1+#2-1} {
        \node at (0, #1+#2-##1-1) {Question}; \node at (1, #1+#2-##1-1) {##1};
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#3} {
            \node[draw,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (####1+1, ##1-#1) {};
            \int_compare:nNnTF {####1} = {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1+#2-##1}} {\node[fill,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (####1+1, ##1-#1) {};}{}
 }
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
}      
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\sffamily\small

\hfill Name: \hspace{2cm}\vspace{1cm} % <===============================

\answergrid      {20} {4} {0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}
\answergrid [21] {20} {4} {0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]