# Multiple Choice Questions with xparse package

Tags: xparse

Please I want to modify the following codes corresponding a multiple choice tabular for obtain a result as in the below image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\answergrid}{ m m m }{
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.6cm]
\seq_set_split:Nnn \splitted_seq{;}{#3}
\newcounter{answer}
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#2} {
\stepcounter{answer}
\node[fill=green!10,draw=black,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (##1+1,#1) {\Alph{answer}};}
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#1} {
\node[fill=black!50,text=white, minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (1, #1-##1) {\bf ##1};
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#2} {
\int_compare:nNnTF {####1} = {\seq_item:Nn \splitted_seq {#1-##1+1}} 
{
\node[fill=red!10,draw,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (####1+1, ##1-1) {};
}
{\node[draw=blue,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (####1+1, ##1-1) {};}
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\par
\answergrid {14} {4} {2;0;0;0;1;0;2;0;0;0;2;0;2;4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please attribute code! This is actually required, I think, but mostly it is just rather rude not to.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285074/mcq-answer-grid-with-tikz/285086#285086, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284495/mcq-answer-grid/285952#285952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219425/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-bubble-answer-sheet-for-multiple-choice-exam. What have you tried by way of adapting the code? What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2):

A different approach.

I heavily edited code from [How to generate a dynamic bubble answer sheet for multiple-choice exam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219425/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-bubble-answer-sheet-for-multiple-choice-exam), but the looping routines were particularly useful.

**REVISED ANSWER**

EDITED to provide `\answergrid{<no.-choices>}{<answer-key>}` interface.  Thus the invocation would be `\answergrid{5}{B;0;0;A;C;0;0;0;0;0;D;0;B;E}` to indicate choices A-E, with 14 questions whose answers are given by the list (`0` indicates no answer specified).

RE-EDITED to allow multiple correct answers for a given question, using the syntax `{B;E}` for a given answer to a question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,amssymb}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\repeatntimes}[2]{%
   \newcount\i%
   \i=0%
   \newtoks\ans%
   \loop%
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}%
      \advance\i by 1%
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat%
   \the\ans%
}
\newcommand{\countRepeatntimes}[2]{%
   \newcount\i%
   \i=0%
   \newtoks\ans%
   \loop%
      \advance\i by 1%
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}%
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat%
   \the\ans%
}
\newcommand\numberbox[1]{\colorbox{black!50}{\makebox[1em]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}
\newcommand\letterbox[2][green!10]{\fcolorbox{blue}{#1}{\makebox[1.2em]{#2}}}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{choice}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\generateQs}[2][0]{%
  \getnextanswer#1;0\relax%
  \countRepeatntimes{#2}{\stepcounter{problem}\savestack{\Prob}{%
    \numberbox{\theproblem}}%
    \setcounter{choice}{0}%
    \repeatntimes{\numexpr\NumberOfChoices-1}{\stepcounter{choice}%
      \if\Alph{choice}\nextanswer\relax%
        \savestack{\Prob}{\stackunder{\Prob}{\letterbox[red!10]{\Alph{choice}}}}%
        \expandafter\getnextanswer\moreanswers;0\relax%
      \else%
        \savestack{\Prob}{\stackunder{\Prob}{\letterbox{\Alph{choice}}}}%
      \fi%
    }\Prob\kern7pt%
  }%
}
\def\getnextanswer#1;#2\relax{%
  \edef\nextanswer{#1}%
  \edef\moreanswers{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\def\NumberOfChoices{4}
\newcommand\answergrid[2]{\renewcommand\NumberOfChoices{#1}\makegrid #2;\relax\relax}
\def\makegrid#1#2#3\relax{%
  \generateQs[#1]{1}\ifx\relax#3\else\makegrid#3\relax\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\answergrid{5}{{B;E};0;0;{A;C;D};C;0;0;0;0;0;D;0;B;E}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The operative macro is `\generateQs[<answer>]{<count>}`.  When an `<answer>` is specified, the `<count>` will typically be `1`, and the answer for that [those] question[s] will be shaded pink (the rest green).  If no `<answer>` is specified, all the possible answers are shaded green and `<count>` can be used to generate a number of such answer blocks.

The number of choices (A-D) is hardwired into `\generateQs` as the argument `3` to `\repeatntimes`.  If the problem count needs resetting, the counter `problem` is that which needs to be reset to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,amssymb}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\repeatntimes}[2]{%
   \newcount\i%
   \i=0%
   \newtoks\ans%
   \loop%
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}%
      \advance\i by 1%
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat%
   \the\ans%
}
\newcommand{\countRepeatntimes}[2]{%
   \newcount\i%
   \i=0%
   \newtoks\ans%
   \loop%
      \advance\i by 1%
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}%
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat%
   \the\ans%
}
\newcommand\numberbox[1]{\colorbox{black!50}{\makebox[1em]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}
\newcommand\letterbox[2][green!10]{\fcolorbox{blue}{#1}{\makebox[1.2em]{#2}}}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{choice}
\newcommand{\generateQs}[2][0]{%
  \countRepeatntimes{#2}{\stepcounter{problem}\savestack{\Prob}{%
    \numberbox{\theproblem}}%
    \setcounter{choice}{0}%
    \repeatntimes{3}{\stepcounter{choice}% <--CHOICE OF {3} PRINTS A,B,C,D
      \if\Alph{choice}#1\relax%
        \savestack{\Prob}{\stackunder{\Prob}{\letterbox[red!10]{\Alph{choice}}}}%
      \else%
        \savestack{\Prob}{\stackunder{\Prob}{\letterbox{\Alph{choice}}}}%
      \fi%
    }\Prob\kern7pt%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\generateQs[B]{1}%
\generateQs{5}
\generateQs[C]{1}%
\generateQs{4}
\generateQs[A]{1}%
\generateQs{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version in which the font size is reduced (to `\scriptsize`), the answer box widths are reduced, the `\fboxsep` is reduced (to 1.5pt), and the inter-question `\kern` is reduced (from 7pt to 5pt).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,amssymb}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\repeatntimes}[2]{%
   \newcount\i%
   \i=0%
   \newtoks\ans%
   \loop%
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}%
      \advance\i by 1%
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat%
   \the\ans%
}
\newcommand{\countRepeatntimes}[2]{%
   \newcount\i%
   \i=0%
   \newtoks\ans%
   \loop%
      \advance\i by 1%
      \ans=\expandafter{\the\ans #2}%
      \ifnum\i<#1\repeat%
   \the\ans%
}
\def\FS{\scriptsize}
\newcommand\numberbox[1]{\colorbox{black!50}{\makebox[.8em]{\textcolor{white}{\FS#1}}}}
\newcommand\letterbox[2][green!10]{\fcolorbox{blue}{#1}{\makebox[1em]{\FS#2}}}
\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{choice}
\newcommand{\generateQs}[2][0]{\fboxsep=1.5pt\relax%
  \countRepeatntimes{#2}{\stepcounter{problem}\savestack{\Prob}{%
    \numberbox{\theproblem}}%
    \setcounter{choice}{0}%
    \repeatntimes{3}{\stepcounter{choice}% <--CHOICE OF {3} PRINTS A,B,C,D
      \if\Alph{choice}#1\relax%
        \savestack{\Prob}{\stackunder{\Prob}{\letterbox[red!10]{\Alph{choice}}}}%
      \else%
        \savestack{\Prob}{\stackunder{\Prob}{\letterbox{\Alph{choice}}}}%
      \fi%
    }\Prob\kern5pt%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\generateQs[B]{1}%
\generateQs{5}
\generateQs[C]{1}%
\generateQs{4}
\generateQs[A]{1}%
\generateQs{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please have you a solution when a question has two or three ... good answers.   I want if possible a solution  as : \answergrid{5}{B;0;0;{A;D};C;0;0;0;0;0;D;0;B;E}

Comment: @user105476 Please see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

add `\newcommand{\rot}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=l]{450}{#1}}` in the preamble and in the body type `\rot{\answergrid {14} {4} {2;0;0;0;1;0;2;0;0;0;2;0;2;4}}` and compile you will the following

[image: gridsol]

Answer (score 1):

Here an other approach but I have a problem to repeat the following code 14 times:

```
\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-n) {\Alph{answer}}; from n=1 to n=14
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xparse}



\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentCommand{\answergrid}{ m m m }{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.6cm, rotate=90]
            \seq_set_split:Nnn \splitted_seq{;}{#3}
            \newcounter{answer}
            \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#2} {
                \stepcounter{answer}


%----> the problem!!! 
\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-1) {\Alph{answer}};
\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm,] at (6-##1,#1-2) {\Alph{answer}};
\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-3) {\Alph{answer}};
\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-4) {\Alph{answer}};
\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-5) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-6) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-7) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-8) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-9) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-10) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-11) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-12) {\Alph{answer}};\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-13) {\Alph{answer}};
\node[fill=green!10,minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-##1,#1-14) {\Alph{answer}};}




            \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#1} {
                \node[fill=black!50,text=white, minimum~width=6mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6, #1-##1) {\bf ##1};
                \int_step_inline:nnnn {1} {1} {#2} {

                    \int_compare:nNnTF {####1} = {\seq_item:Nn \splitted_seq {#1-##1+1}} {
                        \node[fill=red!10,draw,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-####1, ##1-1) {B};
                    }{
                        \node[draw=blue,minimum~width=7mm,minimum~height=4mm] at (6-####1, ##1-1) {};
                    }
                }
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \par

    \answergrid {15} {5} {2;0;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;0}



\end{document}
```